# Can snapshots using Jest be taken on a real device using appium

Tags: reactjs, appium, native, jestjs

If I test my react native app using appium + jest and use the snapshot feature , will the snapshots be taken on the app or mock DOM. I can see the navigation happening with clicks using the  appium  driver and taking snapshots between the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

`Jest` is test framework to design tests

`Appium` is test framework to interact with mobile apps/devices. It's a black-box testing tool, worse to mention.

As you may see in [test example](https://github.com/garthenweb/react-native-e2etest/blob/master/__tests__/basic.e2e.js) `wd.js` is used as client library for Appium.

To check what you can do and how to use it, check [api docs](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md)

To take DOM structure you may use code like this:

```
const source = await driver.source()
```

It will be *XML representation* of your current UI screen, and my guess it may differ from *actual DOM*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not want to take screenshots but leverage the Json Dom representation of data using Jest. So was wondering if I could use it while I run my jest tests on device using wd.

Comment: I updated the answer. Basically appium is a black-box testing tool, so it cannot inject inside your code and get actual structure. But it greps UI components with native framework (UIAutomator/XCUITest) and build XML representation, so that it can use it for elements searching

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I feel the XML representation on the DOM does not capture the styles which the snapshot does

Comment: This is how appium works: if you use non-native strategy e.g. ClassName, it transforms JSON DOM to XML and then perform searching. I don't know the way to get JSON DOM directly via Appium as it doesn't make sense in terms of tool itself

Comment: Thank you for your inputs :)